# Is the content of NSData separately reference-counted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, memory

I have a large malloc'd region that I want to wrap in an NSData object. Some time later, I make a copy of that NSData object. I want the two NSData objects to live independent lifetimes. ARC takes care of ref-counting the NSData objects themselves, but I'm trying to clarify the lifetime of the **contained malloc'd region**. Here's a code sketch:

```
float* cubeData = (float*)malloc(cubeDataSize);
printf("cubeData=%p\n", cubeData);
// cubeData=0x01beef00

for (...) { /* fill the cubeData array */ }

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:cubeData length:cubeDataSize
  freeWhenDone:YES];

NSData* data2 = [data copyWithZone:nil]

printf("data.bytes=%p data2.bytes=%p\n", data.bytes, data2.bytes);
// data.bytes=0x01beef00 data2.bytes=0x01beef00
```

It's OK with me that copyWithZone doesn't deep-copy the malloc'd region — I can use `[NSData dataWithData:]` if I want a deep copy. What isn't clear to me (and I'm not sure how best to test) is which NSData object owns the underlying malloc'd buffer? If they both hold a reference to the malloc'd buffer (using some form of opaque reference counting) that's great! But if the malloc'd buffer gets freed when the `data` object is released (as implied by `freeWhenDone:YES`), `data2` will have trouble on its hands.

Can someone explain what NSData does in this case? Alternatively, can someone suggest a definitive test to prove to myself what's going on?

Comment: For a good time log the pointer address of data and data2. `NSLog(@"%p %p", data, data2);` ;-)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: you mean like the last line in the example? :-) (I used `printf` instead of `NSLog`)

Comment: "If YES, the returned object takes ownership of the bytes pointer and frees it on deallocation."  That says to me that you'd better not count on the buffer surviving beyond the life of the first NSData.  However, probably the second NSData increments the reference count of the first NSData, so the first NSData will not go poof until the second one does.  (In non-ARC you could test reference counts to check this.)

Comment: you logged the bytes. log the addresses of the NSData objects. Spoiler: They are equal. data and data2 point to the exact same object. Immutable objects usually return the same instance when you send `copy`. The copy will just increase the reference count of the object. Is it guaranteed to be this way? Probably not, sounds like a implementation detail. So be extra careful when testing how your code behaves.

Comment: You may also run into the issue that you want to keep a pointer to the underlaying data -- but release the corresponding NSData object prematurely. This can happen when using ARC namely, immediately after the last access to the NSData object, but BEFORE the next access to the interior pointer. This causes a crash. You can however, explicitly extend the lifetime of ARC managed objects with using _attribute objc_precise_lifetime_  e.g.: `NSData* data __attribute__((objc_precise_lifetime)) = ...;`  This extends the lifetime up until the object goes out of block scope.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: my apologies, you're absolutely right about `data` and `data2` pointing to the same object. It hadn't occurred to me that would happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the underlying question:

> Is the content of NSData separately reference-counted?

No. (But looking at your code, it shouldn't matter. See below after this diversion.)

--- Start Diversion ---

ARC manages retains and releases on Objective-C objects by sending the equivalent of `retain` and `release` messages at appropriate times. "Appropriate times" are determined at compile time by code inspection. That is exactly everything it does. When you start creating pointers to non-object pieces of those objects (i.e. `bytes`), you're on your own to manage lifetime.

@CouchDeveloper provides good information about `objc_precise_lifetime`. Placing this attribute on data objects can protect you from an ARC optimizations when dealing with internal pointers, but it isn't really relevant here. The point of `objc_precise_lifetime` is to tell ARC it's not allowed to release an object before the referencing variable goes out of scope. The problem it solves looks like this:

```
NSData *data = ...;
void *stuff = data.bytes; // (1)
doSomething(stuff); // (2)
```

ARC has [an optimization](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#id42) that says it's allowed to destroy `data` between line (1) and line (2), since you never reference `data` again, even though `data` is in scope. Adding the `objc_precise_lifetime` attribute forbids that optimization. When you start using `NSData` a lot, this attribute can become important.

--- End Diversion ---

OK, but what about your situation?

```
float* cubeData = (float*)malloc(cubeDataSize);
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:cubeData length:cubeDataSize freeWhenDone:YES];
NSData* data2 = [data copyWithZone:nil]
```

After this code has run, there are two possibilities (and you're not supposed to care most of the time which is true, since these are immutable objects):

- `data` and `data2` are both strong pointers to the same `NSData` object. That object owns the malloced memory and will free it when deallocated. (This is the one that's almost certain to happen in this particular case, but that's an implementation detail.)
- `data` points to an `NSData` object that owns the malloced memory and will free it when deallocated. `data2` points to a different `NSData` object with its own memory (which it will free when *it* is deallocated.)

(There are other options; perhaps `NSData` uses an underlying `dispatch_data` or a copy-on-write scheme. But all the options should effectively look like the above from the outside.)

In the first case, if `data` goes out of scope, but `data2` is still around, then the owning `NSData` is preserved. No problem. In the second case, when `data` goes out of scope, it destroys its memory, but `data2` has an independent copy of it, so again no problem.

I think your confusion is coming from thinking that `data` owns the memory. It doesn't. The `NSData` object that `data` points to owns the memory. `data` and `data2` are just pointers.

Comment: My confusion came from missing the fact that `data` and `data2` are actually pointing at _exactly the same object_, so (of course) the contained buffer is in turn identical. I had assumed `copyWithZone:` would return a new object, but it doesn't do that (or doesn't in this case, anyway). @MatthiasBauch pointed in the right direction, and your answer explains the situation in much more detail. Thanks!